# Template doesnot exist at login/index

Tags: python, django

I was programming a login system but i don't know why i'm getting this error.The routes are ok.

[look at the circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB8Wo.png)

Comment: Your template should be in `/login/templates/login` folder. You are missing the `templates` in between.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a `templates` directory inside your `login` app, and inside `templates` directory create `login` directory and put your templates there. this can fix the problem.

final directory tree can be something like this:

```
login
---templates
------login
---------index.html
---------fo.html
---------bar.html
```

Answer (score -1):

Django looks for a map called 'templates'. Your map is called Login.

Comment: What is a "map"?

Comment: A directory. Check out SirSaleh's answer.